# I can't get my menu bar to center (CSS)

Tags: css, menu, centering

The menu bar itself is centered but the buttons inside the bar aren't. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I really don't know what I'm doing so any help is appreciated :D.

```
.main-navigation {
   clear:both;
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
 }

nav.main-nav .container {
   padding:0;
   text-align:right;
 }

.container {
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   padding-left:15px;
   padding-right:15px;
 }

ul#primary-menu li a {
   color:#404040;
   font-size:14px;
   font-weight:100;
   letter-spacing:2px;
   margin-right:35px;
   text-decoration:none;
   text-transform:uppercase;
 }

ul#primary-menu > li > a {
   line-height:40px;
 }

.main-navigation a {
   display:block;
   text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Not sure which part of it to copy but the website is virtusknives.com

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your  ".main-navigation", your menu bar should be centered because its width: 100% as long as it is your parent element this should work

```
text-align: center;
```

Also, try putting this in your ul

```
display: block;
<!-- if its horizontal -->
display: inline-block;
```

```css
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  
}
.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 2s;
  transition: color 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Marie603 added a snippet of an example